# Is it possible in Firebird to create a single index with ascending and descending columns?

Tags: index, firebird

For instance, something equivalent to

```
CREATE INDEX Listing_Date_Idx ON ACTIVITY(Listing,Date_ DESC,Time_ DESC);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [syntax for index creation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-idx-create) does not allow for this:

```
CREATE [UNIQUE] [ASC[ENDING] | [DESC[ENDING]] INDEX indexname
   ON tablename
   { (<col> [, <col> ...]) | COMPUTED BY (expression) }

<col>  ::=  a column not of type ARRAY, BLOB or COMPUTED BY
```

As you must set a single order for the entire index, not for each individual column.

However,

> It is quite valid to define both an ascending and a descending index
> on the same column or key set.